# Inherited classes: object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, class

I had a large class that I needed to break into smaller classes.
In this trivial example I just tried to explain how I broke the original class. I need to follow this structure but the error message says **object is not callable**. Something is wrong in `circumference = self.circumference(i)` but I don't understand what.
Anyone can explain and suggest how to fix it? many thanks

```
import numpy as np

class Circumference():
    def __init__(self, r=1):

        self.perimeter =2*np.pi*r
        self.are = np.pi*(r**2)
        self.d = 2*r

class Circumferences():
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.circumference = Circumference()

    def make_more_circumferences(self):
        circumferences = []
        for i in np.arange(1, 10):
            circumference = self.circumference(i)
            circumferences.append(circumference)

circ = Circumferences()
more = circ.make_more_circumferences()
```

Comment: @khushi No, I meant np.arange, for having some values of i (in this case from 1 to 9). 
Didn't I import `Circumference` when I wrote `self.circumference = Circumference()`

Comment: It appears you meant to store *the class*, not *one instance*, on ``Circumferences``. Did you intend to write ``self.circumference = Circumference`` (note the lack of ``()``) in ``__init__``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I meant to store the class `Circumference` but then in `def make_more_circumferences` I want to create several objects, each of them with the attributes specified in the top class (self.perimeter, self.area, self.d)

Comment: If ``self.circumferences`` is ``Circumferences``, your desired behaviour should be exactly what happens.